# How can I open a container when I press the iconbutton?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want an app that could opened a color container when you press a button.

This is the main page:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
    MainPageState createState() => MainPageState();

}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Material (
            color: Colors.black
            child: Center (
              child: IconButton (
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon (
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white, 
                ),
                iconSize: 40.0,
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

}
```

And this is that container:

```
class ColoredContainer extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center (
        child: Container (
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 500.0,
          width: 300.0
        )
      );
    }

}
```

Is there a way to open the container when you press the button? Also is it possible to have an animation when the container pops up? If you can, then how can you add the animation?

Comment: Do you want to open a container in the dialog/popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this. And for animation - try to use `AnimatedContainer` instead of `Container`

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool _isContainerVisible = false;

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold (
          body: Material (
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isContainerVisible = !_isContainerVisible;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  iconSize: 40.0,
                ),
                ColoredContainer(_isContainerVisible)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

}

class ColoredContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  ColoredContainer(this._isContainerVisible);
  final bool _isContainerVisible;

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center (
        child: AnimatedContainer (
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          color: Colors.white,
          height: _isContainerVisible ? 500.0 : 0.0,
          width: _isContainerVisible ? 300.0 : 0.0
        )
      );
    }

}
```

Comment: Or you can use Visibility widget with replacement as 0px sized box. State anyway is required.

Comment: ColoredContainer(this._isContainerVisible); Is getting an error

Comment: Would Like to Mention another Useful Widget - `Offstage` `Offstage(
          child: ColoredContainer(),
          offstage: _isContainerVisible,
        ),`

Comment: @Extra, sorry, my bad - `_isContainerVisible` mustn't be initialized in this case - I've edited the answer

Comment: Edit the answer - how it can be with `AnimatedContainer`

Comment: With `Visibility` or `Offstage` I'm not sure are changes will be animated

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help.